# it ask me for password when i try to open disk and connect to a netwrk

Tags: unity

[image: screenshot]

that's the following problem it is asking me for password i have no idea which password i never kept the password except user password

Comment: Enter your user password.

Comment: i tried but it didnt worked

Comment: Remember that passwords are Case Sensitive. password is NOT the same as Password or passWord. If you've lost or forgotten your password you can reset it. See here: http://askubuntu.com/questions/24006/how-do-i-reset-a-lost-administrative-password

Answer (score 0):

Provided you stick to Ubuntu's default configuration, the authentication password is universal for any action you take on Ubuntu.

Your "user password" is what you need here, now and then to make changes on your system. This is called root access.

In the future, avoid entering the password after opening a downloaded application if you don't trust the source.

Answer (score 0):

The bit that is tripping people up is the prompt isn't asking for **`Password: _____`** as it usually might with a PolicyKit `pkexec` prompt, it's asking for **`Password for root: _____`**.

As [the manpage](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/en/man1/pkexec.1.html) sort of skirts around, this is actually asking for the root account password, ***not*** your account password. This explains why the latter doesn't work.

*Why* it's asking you for the root password is slightly harder to answer. I have a few ideas:

- Your account isn't a member of the required group (not sure which is needed but I'd have a guess at it being `sudo` or `admin`
- You've set a root password and that's somehow upsetting PolicyKit
- The PolicyKit policy for this has been munched somewhere along the line (I don't know where it is so can't suggest a fix for the moment).

[This bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/network-manager/+bug/964705) also seems relevant.